# Do self-identified Christian fundamentalists have their own geographical communities?

Tags: culture, christian-identity, fundamentalism

Do self-identified Christian fundamentalists have their own geographical communities? Surely, it is known that the "Fundamentalist Latter-Day Saints Church" has their own geographical communities, with the headquarters stationed in Utah. There are a couple of isolated Amish communities in the American Northeast (not saying they are fundamentalist!). Since Christian fundamentalists are known for their antagonistic isolation away from the mainstream culture, it becomes plausible that these people may have developed their own geographical communities somewhere.

Comment: Are you asking if they are concentrated in the Bible belt, or actively cloistered in their own walled communes?

Comment: @AffableGeek Both. The point is whether or not self-identified Christian fundamentalists live together in close-knit communities so that they have some sort of support group, not being so lonely in the mainstream culture.

Comment: i used to be part of a [Christian community](http://www.rebaplacefellowship.org/Reba_Connections/Other_Communities) that, itself, was part of a covenant of communities. they weren't <i>quite</i> "fundamentalist", but there <b>were</b> some things they had in common with fundamentalists (like a proscription of women in the top leadership of the church).

Answer (score 7):

No.  Everyone in my local Church self-describes as fundamentalist, and we live 
like normal folk in cities, suburbs, farms, our own houses, apartments, underground survival bunkers with automated home defenses, abandoned missle silos, trees, caves, and just about anywhere else normal people live.

Just joking about the last four on that list...

Our group includes doctors, lawyers, computer programmers, cooks, farmers, car salespersons, mechanics, waitresses, and any job imaginable.

For fun, we like sports, TV, games, video games, movies, playing practical jokes, hanging out with friends, and any normal activity.

Some groups do live in isolated communities, but that's not a characteristic of "fundamentalists".  Separatism is not fundamentalism, and fundamentalism is not separatism.   There is as much diversity within those that self identify as "Fundamentalist" as there is within any other group.